# Storyboard: how to set initial viewcontroller for UIPageViewController with storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-storyboard

I love the storyboard approach. That clearly show the screen havagation logic. I want to specify the initial controller to be used by the UIPageViewController, but it doesn't appear.

Here is my storyboard:
[image: desired storyboard behaviour]

How can I define the segue to ViewControlelr that my UIPageViewController will populate first? I really want this transition to be visually displayed in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

First select the specific controller that you want to make a root controller in the option window and then select is initial controller option it will make that first controller
[image]